How to disable KDE Plasma automatically finding printers?
I'm using KDE Plasma 5.27 with Debian-12.
Everytime I turn on my printer, KDE always add a printer config in its printer list with a strange name, even though I have manually added a config for this printer.
Furthermore, this automatically added one, always interferences my normal printing job. Many software such as Kate probably take this auto-printer as its default printer.
Is there a way, I can disable KDE automatically findding printers in home LAN?

Negtive. KDE always adds a new printer config in few seconds after I delete the one auto found, eventhough I changed BrowseLocalProtocols to 'none'.
